# How to access postgresql pod/service in google kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am deploying a simple web application. I divided it into 3 pods:front end, back end, and postgres db. I successfully deployed my front end and back end to google kubernetes service and they works as expected. But for my postgresql db server, I used the following yamls. The postgres image is created by me using standard postgres images from dockerhub. I created some tables, and inserted some data and pushed to DockerHub. My backend is not able to make connection to my db. I think I might need to change my Java connection code.Not sure on using localhost. It works without any issue on my local Eclipse Jee and Tomcat.

```
//my pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: postgres-app-pod
   labels:
      name: postgres-app-pod
      app: demo-geo-app
spec:
   containers:
   - name: postgres
     image: myrepo/example:v1
     ports:
     - containerPort: 5432

//my service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: db
   labels:
      name: db-service
      app: demo-geo-app
spec:
   ports:
   - port: 5432
     targetPort: 5432
   selector:
      name: postgres-pod
      app: demo-geo-app 

   //from my java backend, I access my db server this way.
String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Location?user=postgres&password=mysecretpassword";
```

Comment: You will be accessing the postgres service with its name, in your case it is `db`.
Changing your code like this will help:
`String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/Locationuser=postgres&password=mysecretpassword";
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two issues to be fixed.

1. the service selector key:value should match with pod labels
2. replace localhost with postgresql service dns

Comment: Is there a way to know the service DNS in a simple scenario like Minikube? When I use a similar scenario as the above with a deployment+service, then I cannot connect even if I use the IP address I get from the output of the command `minikube service my-db-service --namespace my-namespace`. I don't think the issue is the DNS, but I can see the K8S Service is up and running, so I am not sure what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

As per comments you have an error on your connection string, localhost is referring to the same pod where you are running the Java code, you need to change to `db` as the same name you put on the service yaml to work.

I recommend you to use a deployment instead of `Pod` on the type, but in that case that you are trying to deploy a database  you need to use a `StatefulSet` please review the documentation

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

Also, I recommend you to check https://helm.sh you have a lot of chart ready to use instead of having to code from scratch a service like a database.

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql

On that chart you have all the necessary yaml ready including the PVC provisioning.